# Android - Multiple application names in manifest - Universal Image Loader and ACRA

Tags: android, manifest, universal-image-loader, acra

so you know, I've been using ACRA for a while to allow users to send crash reports via email.

As i have researched, you can only have one instance of an application in the manifest, and unfortunately ACRA is that one application in the manifest. Recently, i started using the Universal Image Loader library, so  i had to change the one application in the manifest to UIL from ACRA.

Basically, my question is how can i put two applications in one manifest? Most likely, from what i said above, is almost impossible, so is there a way to extend applications in the manifest or integrate code from ACRA to get it to work when the app crashed.

If needed, i can show source code of my app's manifest.

Thanks for your help anyone. It is getting really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. I have initialized ACRA and UIL both at once:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
   .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
// for acra
ACRA.init(this);
}
}
```

Dont forget to add the internet permission in your manifest. And give your application a name:

```
  <application android:name="MyApplication">
```

Comment: Would UIL run first? It seems with that code, it initializes UIL when it crashes? Not sure. Could i reverse this, if thats the case. Like use "<application android:name="UIL">" and hard code or initialize ACRA within UIL, to make it start listening for crashes?

Comment: Or will it still run UIL and show my images first but then if a crash happens, ACRA takes in effect to handle it?

Comment: it doesnot matter what you do first uil or arca the oncreate method is specific for your application so either would work.

Comment: It worked great the first time i responded to you. Thanks alot.

Comment: glad I helped see ya around